# MATLAB documentation: what's the purpose?

Tags: documentation, discussion

I'll be short and clear - MATLAB already has a great(!) [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/index.html). I have learned almost everything I know in it directly from the official documentation, and they are exhaustive, clear, give good examples and a sometimes even an introduction to the subject.

So what exactly are we trying to achieve in re-documenting it? Unlike open-source software and programming languages, there's a group of people that get paid just for doing that, and not like in other software (for instance, Excel that have a not-so-good documentation) they are doing a great job, and also ensure that it's kept up-to-date.

Indeed, [some holes can be find within the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232912/matlab-todo-fill-in-description), but that's what Stack Overflow Q&A is about - specific questions about well-defined topics. Don't get me wrong, I think this documentation initiative is **great** for a lot of reasons, just in the case of MATLAB (which I happen to know better than any other language) I find myself wondering "How do I contribute without simply copying MATLAB docs? and why should anyone look for the answers here instead of the original documentation?"

I would be more than glad to be convinced that it is a needed service, and I'll be happy to contribute as far as I can (with my humble knowledge) as soon as I understand the goal more clearly.

Comment: What problems would having the documentation on both sites? Yes you can learn great stuff from official documentation but that doesn't mean that other sources of documentation are not more useful to other people.

Comment: @JoeW I never said it is a problem, but where people investing time and effort in this project I think they wish to more than just replicate the original docs in a different structure

Comment: Have you ever tried using the xPCTarget documentation? *Its horrid!* And the example models for RS232 serial com are even worse. There's definitely a gap to fill here.

Comment: "...and why should anyone look for the answers here instead of the original documentation?" That one is easy to answer. One should always look where information is displayed better or where information is contained that is not presented somewhere else. Since per definition nothing is perfect, there is always room for improvement. The real question is if we should rather improve the already great(!) Matlab documentation (by sending Mathworks examples etc.) or contribute to just another Matlab tutorial with examples or stay on Q&A with our examples? I don't know what is better.

Comment: For some of their toolboxes the documentation stinks. Some of the machine learning toolboxes, for instance. Obviously we don't need to rewrite documentation for `sum`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To summarise (because I went on too much on my previous attempt to answer), the MATLAB documentation on Stack Overflow can be useful ...

because:

1. Not everybody reads the official documentation (of any program for
   that matter), yet some would read (a documentation built through)
   practical examples and try to apply/modify to their need.
2. Sometimes people need to hear/see things in a different manner than
   the mainstream way of explaining it; this could be a place for that.
3. MATLAB documentation is great indeed, yet most examples focus on the specific function they are illustrating. Only seldomly is this connected to wider topics. The documentation here could rejoin some of these lonely functionalities that work a lot better as part of a group
   than on their own.
4. The MATLAB documentation is not perfect and some holes can be plugged.
5. As Brendan suggested, the Documentation would be a great place to
   organise a collection of *canonical* solutions to the most-asked
   questions which keep popping up again and again.

for:

1. Experienced (and less experienced) programmers looking for a place
   where the most useful trick/answer/hack can be found easily (I don't
   know about yourself, but I find having to search back for an answer,
   I remembered was fantastic, but I forgot to put in 'favourite', a
   real pain in the backside...).
2. Novice programmers, specially the one who understand better through
   example than lecture.
3. The MATLAB Stack Overflow community of answerers, who could redirect (too) common questions to the "canonical" answers (see point (5) above), instead
   of having to find the best duplicate (because some questions have
   been asked so many times than many non-closed duplicate exists, with
   sometimes several quality answers).

Now I agree it would be a waste if the documentation here was a simple copy/paste of the official documentation. The Stack Overflow Documentation needs to be an addition to the existing documentation, or for some topic an alternative version explained in a different light.

As you said in the comment to your question, *people investing time and effort in this project wish to more than just replicate the original documentation*. I left the last bit ("*in a different structure*") out because the fact is a huge number of MATLAB question on Stack Overflow could be just answered by quoting the documentation, but for the class of people described below, it ***needs*** to be in a different structure to be considered/looked at/useful.

If you are a teacher and have only one strict way of explaining something, half of your students will never get it ... if you can explain it in a variety of ways, you'll get through to a lot more of them.

---

<sub>The two paragraph below were two distinct attempt to answer your questions. I've finally summarized them above so you can stop reading here if you've had enough. They do explain/illustrate a bit more some of my statements above though, so I leave the text for people curious.</sub>

---

**MATLAB documentation is not for everybody:**

MATLAB official documentation is good, very good even, but it is only useful to people who (i) understand it, and/or (ii) actually take the time to read it before swarming Stack Overflow with the same low-level questions which appear and reappear every second day.

Granted the Stack Overflow Documentation will not stop the people described in the second group above, but it could still improve the "*Time to resolution*" for a portion of this questions: Quite a number of these questions come from people "allergic" to most official documentation. Either by pure laziness or because they've come across so much other "bad" documentation, the fact is that now they *modus operandi* when confronted to a new problem is to look straight for "code samples" which does their stuff or close to it. If they can't find any, they just ask for it, on miscellaneous forums or here on Stack Overflow.

For these people, a link to the official documentation will be dismissed as quickly as it came, while a link to some "practical examples", hosted on the same site (*I deliberately didn't call it "documentation" to not scare them ...*) will be considered by at list a percentage of these askers. (now the next thing to do is to convince them to close their question if they got it solved, but that's another point).

---

**MATLAB documentation is evolving:**

I strongly agree with the statement "MATLAB documentation is good". I also have learnt so much from it, and it's not finished. I still go back to it often, even sometimes for functions I use with my eyes closed, because it is also evolving and new pearls can be found at unexpected times.

However, having seen the evolution since MATLAB v5, while it is true that it mostly evolved for the better, I have witnessed a few "changes" that I believe were degrading its usefulness. I'll illustrate that with an example, on a topic which triggers quite a few questions on Stack Overflow.

Take the function  `interp1`. It's a fantastic, easy-to-use yet very powerful, mean of data manipulations. The first time I needed to use it ~15 years ago, I searched for "*interpolation in MATLAB*" and was quickly directed to the `interp1` documentation. There I immediately understood how to use the syntax given at the time:

```
yi = interp1(x,Y,xi)
```

by seeing the image (which was part of the official documentation):
[image: interp illustration]

I can't remember in which edition the image disappeared, but it is not there any more, and despite a long list of (good) examples now present in the documentation, a simple search on Stack Overflow returns quite a few questions about this function, and a significant portion of them has to do with the user just not understanding the syntax properly.
The Stack Overflow Documentation could fix some of these losses.

Comment: First - great answer! (read it all) I think you touched most of the doubts I had about this documentation. To summarize, and by that see if I get you right (and also present my point of view), this documentation will benefit the most from integrating topics and a handful of **good** examples. I'm totally agree that explaining the same thing in a different way may get more users to understand, though I do not feel like investing my time in supporting those who didn't even ask google before they post a question. I hope that this project will lead to some new, different way to learn MatLab.

Comment: "Not everybody reads the official documentation (of any program for that matter), yet some would read (a documentation built through) practical examples and try to apply/modify to their need." According to [Adriaan](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328744/matlab-documentation-whats-the-purpose/329933?noredirect=1#comment375263_329933) the practical examples would already be covered by proper questions on SO. So the question would be if Documentation is necessary or delivers a big advantage over Q&A in presenting practical examples?

Answer (score 9):

Maybe it isn't needed.

I mean, that's a possibility. There's a *lot* of not-so-great documentation out there, and even more documentation that simply doesn't exist... But where it does, and where it's good, there's no pressing need to do anything. Maybe MATLAB is one of those cases.

Then again, there are rather a lot of MATLAB *questions* on Stack Overflow. It's possible that at least a small portion of those exist because the authors couldn't find the right documentation, or found the examples lacking in some way. At least a few people have apparently seen a need, and started work on documenting some areas of MATLAB; whether that ends up being useful remains to be seen.

In any case, if it turns out there *is* a need, the capability now exists. If it's useful, great! If it isn't... Well, that just means things are already pretty great!

Answer (score 1):

I would say the nomenclature for the Documentation hints at that pretty strongly.  They aren't called *sections*, or *packages*, or *modules* in Documentation.  They're called *topics* and *examples*.

Official (or unofficial) documentation is usually pretty good as an API reference, and for some projects (like MATLAB) it's also pretty good at providing examples of how to use specific features of the API.  But one area were most documentation suffers is providing larger examples for various tasks that utilize multiple portions of the library, or use multiple libraries.

Until now, I think the mindset was to handle theses situations by providing "canonical" answers that were somewhat general and then closing all related answers as duplicates of the canonical answer, or by linking to the canonical answer, and then providing some modifications and context in the new question.

It seems like Documentation is a better place to organize these *canonical* solutions and examples.

Comment: But then it shouldn't be called "documentation". Also, I find the overlapping with actual canonical answers disturbing

Answer (score -2):

I see Documentation as the place to create Documentation where it doesn't exist or isn't in good shape or a place where you can add parts of Documentation that do not exist or aren't in good shape. Furthermore it's example centric.

Matlab documentation is in good shape and does exist and even is example centric.

However, it is far from being perfect. Not every behavior is documented, not everywhere examples are given. These could be added here.

Also, some things are surprisingly difficult in Matlab (rendering an axis content to file, drawing a circle, ...) which could be discussed here.

Synopsis: We should avoid duplicating Matlab's superb documentation, but we should complement it.

Comment: Undocumented behaviour is undocumented for a reason: it's not fully supported in program updates. If you use UD functions, they can disappear in the next version without warning, meaning that every version update you'd need to rediscover all UD functions. As to your "difficult things", well, that's what we have canonical questions for. A documentation page for "How to draw a circle in MATLAB" is not any different from a proper question on SO.

Comment: @Adriaan Why writing about undocumented behavior? I never mentioned such. As for the proper questions on SO. Well in this case you better argue for closing Documentation altogether. It's example centric. This is nothing you cannot also kind of achieve with a proper question on SO. As I understood Documentation the difference is there that the example comes without the need of a question. But maybe it's actually two times the same thing, only in a slightly different disguise.

Comment: *Not every behavior is documented,(...)These could be added here.* How's that not speaking about undocumented behaviour?

Comment: @Adriaan Oh sorry. I didn't meant undocumented behaviour per se but rather points where the official documentation is vague and/or is missing important points. I didn't think about secret functions that will change often but rather the stuff that is officially there but works a bit different than what is written officially. For example: I know of issues with clipping of ui elements that are not documented on Mathworks. What you see is actually not what they suggest should happen. It would be nice if this could be documented somewhere. Things like this.