# Qualify participants by standards/examples test not rep

Tags: feature-request, documentation

The Q&A review process tests reviewers occasionally and implements temporary review bans when applicable.

Why is there nothing similar in Documentation? Anyone can enter or review whatever they want without any frame of reference to compare it to.

Perhaps a requirement of documentation participants should be that they first pass a standards test, or at lest go through some sort of standards presentation to help prevent garbage getting into the system in the first place and minimize review and clean up chores.

Having to go through a variety of examples of entries that each show a rejected version , a better version and a best version might help bring some sanity to the whole process and create better consistency throughout

Comment: I like more this approach [Minimum tag score for adding documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328978)

Comment: The idea of tests has been brought up in other contexts (as a barrier of entry to contributing to Q&A, to perform review tasks, etc.) and rejected, for good reason. Tests are kind of silly, and what exactly would we want to test when neither form nor function of Documentation are really clearly hashed out yet? We have another rough measure of trust, though, that already exists: reputation.

Comment: @Pekka웃 don't call it a test then. Call it  a standards presentation or whatever. Might  also be able to used as a reference for rejections

Comment: A "standards test", is unfortunately putting the cart before the horse here, since [the intention is apparently for standards to be emergent](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328351/).

Comment: @JoshCaswell maybe they didn't have sidewalks but there weren't farm animals involved either wandering around aimlessly and doing their dirty business wherever they feel. They probably had a  code of ethics too

Comment: A well-expanded analogy, @charlietfl! I certainly don't disagree with you.

Answer (score 3):

> a standards test

But what are the "standards"?

For Q&A, this can be answered from a huge pile of entries that already exist and that were voted, edited, closed, etc.

For documentation, there's yet insufficient data to decide what a good contribution is. And there isn't even a community agreed standard for everything yet.

While employing such tests eventually for the same reasons they exist for Q&A seems legit to me,  I doubt that they make sense now.

Comment: maybe the term "test" is not right and "presentation" would be better. It sure wouldn't be hard to go though and find numerous examples that were rejected or through edit history were improved to better then best to at least have some point of reference as a starting point. Assuming people will follow what is already set doesn't work