# Documentation by example: Example of good documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation

The apparent foundation of Docs.SO is the belief that examples are more important than text. That seeing an example communicates better than words.

There appears to be a general misunderstanding about how Docs.SO is designed to work. Right now, we have lots of people with their own idea of what the concepts of "topic" and "example" mean.

If examples are indeed a better way of communicating, then I would like to challenge the designers of Docs.SO. Go into the various tags and post links to topics that represent *exactly* how Docs.SO is supposed to work. Others can do that too, but I would be curious to see what the people behind this site's design think about the documentation currently available.

Give us an example of superlative Docs.SO-style documentation.

Comment: Ties in with my suggestion of going through some sort of [presentation/test of the good the bad and the ugly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329286/qualify-participants-by-standards-test-not-rep) before unleashing the masses on creating and approving crap

Comment: So basically, do what should have been done during the private beta? Sounds reasonable.

Comment: Honestly, this seems like something that will emerge as the community matures around documentation.

Answer (score 13):

Our SRE Team has been using Documentation since early in the private beta to host usage exmples of [Bosun](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bosun/topics), their [open source monitoring system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/11/announcing-bosun-our-new-open-source-monitoring-alerting-system/). I personally found the [introductory topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bosun/565/overview-a-monitoring-and-alerting-ide#t=201607260656372152222) helpful for setting up a Bosun instance on my machine. (I'm experimenting with several site metrics that may help us keep track of [our network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#users). It's on a back burner at the moment.)

A few things I appreciate about their efforts:

1. The SREs started dogfooding Documentation on their own. They figured out how to create useful examples and organize by topic without us providing any hints. Both during the private and public betas, they've used public channels (mostly [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A17373+%5Bdocumentation%5D)) to get support and report bugs.
2. Bosun's official documentation is hosted on [their site](http://bosun.org/quickstart#bosun). There's no plans on moving that content. Instead, the examples hosted on Stack Overflow augment the canonical documentation.
3. The team makes used of Requested Topics and Improvement Requests to  plan publicly and give the community space to contribute. There's even been [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/11385) can from outside their team.
4. Topics range from 1 to 7 examples. There aren't any kitchen-sink topics (though [Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bosun/612/notifications#t=201607260725084855153) might be a bit broad). Some topics eschew Syntax, Parameters and Remarks when they don't add anything. The examples themselves get to the point quickly and avoid unnecessary explanation. They assume you already know the basics of using Bosun and link to more detailed documentation when it would help the reader.

This is a great example of how a small project can make use of Documentation to supplement other resources. In fact, the best uses of the feature seem to be the smaller Stack Overflow tags. I think the problem with big tags at the moment is everyone is kicking the tires in tags they know well. It's perhaps an example of [Parkinson's law of triviality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality).

Comment: You name this as "a great example of how a small project can make use of Documentation". Is Docs.SO supposed to be used by projects or teams? This is not what I see right now. Most tags are contributed to my many different people that are in no way related or work together as a team or project.

Comment: s/tags they know well/tags they think they know well/

Comment: @Full Name: Those are the "big tags" alluded to in the last couple of sentences.

Comment: @FullName: My guess is that tags will follow a [power law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law) with a small number of very popular tags aborbing the majority of contributions. But the really interesting stuff will be going on at the long end of the tail. Unfortunately, that content is far less visible than Java and C#.

Comment: I see. The problem right now is that the "big tags" are prominent on both the Docs.SO start page and, of course, the list of SO questions tagged with them. So Docs.SO will attract more of this questionable controbutions instead.

Comment: @FullName I think the disconnect here is, _it's not a mutually-exclusive thing._ Individuals AND teams (or, basically anyone) can use it. I could use it to write more real-world examples to augment PHP's manual, and so could PHP if they wanted to. The audience isn't granularly defined because it's simply "anyone that wants to contribute something".

Comment: The original question was for the SO team to show good examples. This discussion makes me think that good usage of Docs.SO will *not* be found in the Java or Python tags, for example. Again it seems that SO is more about quantity instead of quality.

Comment: I think some of the Python Topics are pretty good, if a bit wordy. The [map examples](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/333/map-function#t=201607260800186797841) taught me something as a novice to the language. Other then excessive length, quality of the final content seems to be trending up, though I certainly understand not being able to see that while entrenched reviewing unproductive "Hello World" bikeshedding edits.

Comment: @FullName That's quite a part of the challenge, ensuring that quantity doesn't rule over quality. But here, give it a bit of time.

Comment: @JonEricson heh… cheaters! … While it certainly isn't a bad idea to document it [bosun], currently the system prevents documentation to be used by lower profile tags via the requirements. But it's still in beta, so that's fine for now. I just think, when it goes out of beta, _if_ you also target small teams, it should then drop most of the requirements for creating the tag.

Comment: So far the only answer to the request to provide good examples is not applicable to the "big tags" which will form the bulk for Docs.SO content. Are there no other good examples? Please, SO people, step forward and show us what you thought how Docs.SO should be used.

Comment: @bwoebi this was one reason the SRE team jumped in during the beta, to see if it could work for small teams and low traffic tags. Still some tuning to do and many fires to put out right now, but hopefully it can eventually be opened up to other tags/teams eventually

Comment: I also have liked the progression of the PowerShell and Docker tags, which have had a lot more contributors than the Bosun tag which was largely worked on during the private beta. Now that the site is public we have been encouraging other Bosun users in our slack channel to submit improvements/requests/topics.

Comment: This is a good start. From the example we've been given, Docs.SO is meant to work best when: 1) Examples are just code with maybe a blurb or two of text. 2) Example code can be short, so APIs that are long-winded need not apply. 3) There is existing external documentation which can explain the details of the code. 4) Examples should assume the reader is familiar with the system being used. 5) Everything is written by a small cloister of people who know each other and agree on how it's supposed to work. Am I understanding things correctly?

Comment: 6) The people creating this documentation have no motive for doing so other than writing good examples.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Have you read my [problem with intrinsic motivation rant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42481/1438)? Reputation _screws up_ motivation if you let it consume you. But it's _necessary_ to have systems like reputation in order to have a real community. See: [A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy](http://www.shirky.com/writings/herecomeseverybody/group_enemy.html).

Comment: @NicolBolas: On #2: I think having a tight API helps. But the real problem is that people naturally prefer completeness to the detriment of clarity. We are considering a few restrictions that might help. Long term, we need to make sure the community has the tools to curtail bikeshedding. It took _years_ to get that stuff right (or rather, better) on Q&A. For now, I'd suggest people focus on contributing narrow topics and not worry about the broad topics. Bikeshedding won't be rewarded in the long run.

Comment: @JonEricson: "*I think having a tight API helps.*" I would consider Vulkan to be a very tight API. Every parameter in Vulkan is important and nothing is redundant. However, because it is a very *explicit* API, you have to supply a *huge* number of parameters to pretty much every function. As such, there can be no such thing as a "short" example of doing anything in Vulkan.

Comment: @JonEricson: "*But it's necessary to have systems like reputation in order to have a real community.*" Wikipedia shows that it is not *necessary* to have that system be an algorithm. Wikipedia's equivalent to reputation is very ad-hoc rather than algorithmic. There are no numbers; privileges in Wikipedia cannot be gained automatically. They only come via *human* review. You can play politics in such a system of course, but you cannot automatically *game* it the way Docs.SO rep can be.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It's not purely a question of having short examples, per se. Rather the question is "Can someone who wants to use the API absorb the example in a reasonable timeframe?" So many topics with lots of activity end up with rambly explanations and multiple, unrelated code blocks. That's stuff would have happened _no matter the motivation_. People want to work on Docs because it's new _and_ rewarding. Eventually this feature won't be new anymore.

Comment: This is just never going to work in C++, then. There's no way to make the examples "simple" enough. You omit details and the community will freak out because it isn't precise enough. It really only seems to work for small, simple APIs. There's no way we're going to document Win32, HTML, CSS, C#, Java, etc. You say people are moving to document these because of Parkinson's law of triviality, but I don't think that's true at all. People are moving to document these because *they are what they use the most*. Sure, they know 'em the best, but they also think they're the most useful to document.

Comment: You are going to have to make *massive* changes in the system to *discourage* any attempt to document common languages and APIs. Not that I think that's a bad thing. Most of those are already well-documented elsewhere, and would not benefit from having that documentation "ported" over to Stack Overflow and separately maintained. My radical suggestion would be to simply *disable* Documentation for the biggest of tags. (By a human, of course, for sanity reasons.) With the proposed upcoming changes like the addition of a review queue, documenting smaller tags will actually work.

Comment: Reading some of the comments, you say *"the real problem is that people naturally prefer completeness to the detriment of clarity...we need to make sure the community has the tools to curtail bikeshedding. It took years to get that stuff right (or rather, better) on Q&A."* But those have nothing to do with one another! Q&A encourages completeness because there are no artificial restrictions on length. All the good, top-rated C++ answers are exceptionally complete, even though they take take time to digest. This isn't simply bikeshedding. You fundamentally misrepresent programming as easy!

Comment: @CodyGray: I feel like you are misrepresenting my comments and my answer. Let me use an example: my first question on SO was [Under what circumstances is it acceptable to break a public interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/96116/1438) Seemed reasonable to ask at the time, but it's too broad and every opinion is valid. That's what I mean, not how long or complete a C++ answer might be. So when people change variable names or add their own pet way to do something to already large topic, I see a similar pattern starting on Docs. Nothing wrong with being complete if you consider the reader.

Comment: I've read it several times, and come back on a couple of different days thinking it might just be my mindset, but I honestly cannot make sense of your last comment or what it has to do with my representation of your statements. So you asked a question on SO that was "too broad". What is the relevance of that? It is not too broad because of the complexities of the language and the difficulties in distilling those down into simple, easy-to-digest examples, which is what I was talking about. And it doesn't appear to be something that you'd cover on Docs, either.

Answer (score 2):

> The reason that we didn't give a whole ton of guidance on what to create and how to organize it is because you, as the largest group of developers on Planet Earth are a lot better at figuring that out together. We're here to help guide it, but we need to see how you actually want to use it, and work to support the best use cases.

*Tim Post, Director of Stack Overflow Communities* in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329469/2002588)

---

Having made and reviewed a lot of examples, an also from experience in chats with the community, personally I give you these advices:

- If there is a tag that is more directly related to the topic/example, it should be there instead of where it is, e.g. DOM is an API used with JavaScript, all the DOM specific examples and topics should be in the DOM tag. (Of course they're not..., they're all in JavaScript)
- A topic should be created only if the topic can be covered in more than 3 to 5 examples, if not, the examples should be moved into a broader topic (that should be created if it doesn't exist)
- There shouldn't be duplicated content between examples/topics in the whole site, content should be linked, not duplicated.
- If a topic contains more than 20 to 30 examples, it should be split into 2 to 4 different topics.
- Features not basic to the tag being documented that are referenced to or used in the example should be linked. Not everybody know everything.
- If you are splitting your example in sections (e.g. 4 titles with their respective code and prose), take each of those sections and make different examples.
- If your example is more than two screens long, review it, remove too specific information, search for already documented information and link to it instead of duplicating it, and if all that fails, split it into two different examples if possible.
- If the user can't see a code snippet after 0 to 15 lines of prose, you're doing something wrong.
- If the edit doesn't follow coding conventions only link to those conventions in comments if it's very good, otherwise also reject it.
- If the edit has typos, comment on those typos so the user that made it can retract the draft and make the proper corrections, don't reject it!
- If an edit or example is not grammatically acceptable, but the code is pretty good, approve it, and then edit it if you want. Not everybody speaks english perfectly.

Comment: "*covered in more than 3 to 5 examples*" Perhaps you mean fewer than. "*If your example is more than two screens long, review it, remove too specific information, search for already documented information and link to it instead of duplicating it, and if all that fails, split it into two different examples if possible.*" Then I guess Docs.SO is *never* going to work with Vulkan. You can't even create a *shader* with less than 2 screens of code...

Comment: @NicolBolas no, i think topics should have more than 3 to 5 examples, if not they're not broad enough to be considered a topic. If you understood something else, i might have to rephrase that. Of course there will be exceptions, the idea is to give guidance, not strict rules.