# Another suggestion for doc editing: weighted approval votes

Tags: feature-request, documentation, tag-score

A couple motivating principles:

1. Editing and reviewing should be open to everyone.
2. The higher a user's tag score, the smoother their process for contributing to docs.

## Proposal

Folks vote to approve or reject edits as we do now.

- When the net vote reaches +5 it is accepted and at -3 it is rejected.
- **Votes by users with greater tag score carry extra weight**
   (say 6 for gold; 4 silver; and 2 bronze).
- Half of a user's weight goes towards approval of any edit they propose
   (so a proposal by a gold badger starts at +3; silver at +2; bronze at +1).

A net-score rule like this is used currently for tag synonyms (+4 passes, -2 fails); and tag weight is similar to the dupe hammer.

## Benefits

Going back to the two motivating points:

1. In contrast with a different proposal I liked -- [Minimum tag score for adding documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328978/minimum-tag-score-for-adding-documentation), we would not be ["limiting contributions to people who clear an arbitrary (if rational) bar"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329551/1191259), so participation would be open to everyone.
2. Established SO users will not be demotivated to participate by the need to spend a lot of time managing low-quality, robo-approved contributions.

## Details

Some users may prefer to contribute to docs rather than Q&A. We should give them some path to become "established" contributors to a tag, too. However, it is hard to recognize expertise in the context of docs, so I'd just go with crude rules based on quantity, rather than quality:

> Performing 250 reviews in a tag gets you +1 tag weight; and making 250 accepted edits gets you another +1, up to a max of the 6 of a gold badger. Rejections and review audit failures could count against a user's total. For editing purposes, "half a user's weight" could mean half, rounded up.

For small tags, gold, silver and bronze badges may be too high a set of bars; and for large tags, they may be too low. The rules could be on a scale, perhaps:

> A small tag (500-2,500 questions) has open editing and review as we have now; while a larger tag (2,500+ questions) has the rules described above.

Fwiw, I just found [a discussion post with a similar idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328916/a-change-in-opinion-on-documentation-and-an-idea-to-preserve-quality).

Comment: I think that all this complexities could just be avoided if we just discriminated who can propose changes.

Comment: @Braiam I am inclined to agree, but it seems to go against SO principles as explained in Jon's quote saying they do not want to be "limiting contributions to people who clear an arbitrary (if rational) bar" (linked in the OP). Besides, it's more complicated than a dupe hammer, but not by much (at least as I see it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some changes along the same lines [are now in place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331663/) that make this request obsolete:

> We've just enabled an update to creating and review proposed changes, so that now:
>
> - Users with a silver or gold tag badge (from Q&A) will skip review when they make an edit to that tag's documentation
>
>   - This include aliases, so a [sql-server-2008-r2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008-r2) silver badge will work on [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)'s documentation
>   - If multiple tags are involved (because of moving examples, or submitting multiple topic changes as one) you must have a badge in
>       each tag to skip review
> - Users with a silver or gold tag badge can one-click approve or reject a proposed change from another user to that tag's documentation
> - Review now take 4 "votes" to approve or reject, and how many votes a users approval or rejection counts for is based on their reputation
>
>   - users with >= 10,000 rep get 3 votes
>   - users with >= 1,000 rep get 2 votes
>   - users with >= 100 rep get 1 vote

So now badges come with greater powers; and, for the badgeless, rep carries voting weight.

Comment: I like these changes, but feel that small edits should be listed for review, with a few caveats: All changes that modify 50(?) or fewer characters are pooled into a single, uncredited "Proposed small changes" edit, which is then placed in the review queue.  Any small edits made while a "Proposed small changes" edit is queued will be combined with the queued proposal, which will then be retracted and replaced with the updated version.  This is to prevent minor rep-farming cleanup edits, or conversely, allowing people to make typo fixes without artificially inflating their own reputation.

Comment: Significant edits, of course, would go through the system normally, without pooling.  Hopefully, this would subtly encourage people that want to rep-farm to actually take the time to make a helpful edit, whether adding new information, removing or fixing erroneous examples, rewording unclear sections, etc.

Comment: If a user already has credited edits to an example, then small edits by that user are likely serial editing, where they notice a problem with their previous edit, and fix it.  I'm unsure of whether these serial edits should go in this hypothetical "Proposed small changes" queue, or go through the system normally.

Comment: @Justin Those are interesting ideas. I think you'll be better able to find an audience for them by asking a question to start a new discussion. I closed this question because I think the changes mentioned in the link pretty well addressed the concerns I brought up in the OP. I was concerned more about controlling the direction a doc takes, rather than preventing rep farming. Note: I wrote both the question and answer here :)