# A suggestion for helping to deal with Documentation rep-farming

Tags: feature-request, documentation, reputation

After reading a question about [weighted Documentation approval votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329718/5386374), and the quoted segment from [today's Documentation Update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th), I feel that all small edits should be listed for review, with a few caveats:

- All changes that modify 50(?) or fewer characters are pooled into a single, uncredited "Proposed small changes" edit, which is then placed in the review queue.  [Number can be changed; it should be large enough to cover most cleanup, but small enough to not accidentally catch any significant edits.]
- Any small edits made while a "Proposed small changes" edit is queued will be combined with the queued proposal, which will then be retracted and replaced with the updated version.

This is to prevent minor rep-farming cleanup edits, or conversely, allow people to make typo fixes without artificially inflating their own reputation.

Significant edits, of course, would go through the system normally, without pooling. Hopefully, this would subtly encourage people that want to rep-farm to actually take the time to make a helpful edit, whether adding new information, removing or fixing erroneous examples, rewording unclear sections, etc.  If so, it would help improve the overall quality of edits; most people adding helpful documentation would be unaffected (except in cases where they fix an example that has a small, but significant, error), while rep-farmers would need to put additional effort into proposals if they wanted to gain reputation from them.

If a user already has credited edits to an example, then small edits by that user are likely serial editing, where they notice a problem with their previous edit, and fix it. I'm unsure of whether these serial edits should go in this hypothetical "Proposed small changes" queue, automatically be approved, or go through the system normally; if this idea is implemented, someone with a better view of the big picture would need to make this decision.

So... does this sound like a viable idea, and if not, could it be reworked into one?

Comment: Do you have proof that users are actually trying to farm rep and not just trying to help? And why not reward those who help?

Comment: @Laurel No definitive proof, but a lot of people suspect that small edits are being made on popular topics for the primary purpose of getting reputation when they're upvoted.  Regardless of whether or not it's true, this idea would help give some of the people that are wary of Documentation rep gains peace of mind.  Also, if all one does is a minor change like adding a period, removing an apostrophe, reordering entries in a list without changing them, etc., they're not really _contributing_ to the example, but _proofreading_ it; there appears to be a sentiment against treating the two equally.

Comment: The inability to "improve edit" is at least partially at fault there. There is no other opportunity to make adjustments. They will fix that at some point.

Comment: @Laurel That's good, and it would indeed help with this a good deal.  Wouldn't fully solve the potential problem, but it would be a good start.  It might also be useful to do some profiling, and determine how much, if any, reputation is being gained daily from small "cleanup" edits, to determine whether there's need of any attempts to stem rep farming.